# Uncaught Reference Error: [...] is not defined

Tags: javascript

```
   function deleteTripEntry(tripEntryId) {
    var r = confirm("Do you want to Delete Entry...!");
    if (r == true) {
        $.post(contextApplicationPath
                + '/OutWardGoodsController/deleteTripEntry', {
            tripEntryId : tripEntryId
        }, function(data) {
            tripList();
            alert(data.MSG);
        }, 'json');
    }
}
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: contextApplicationPath is not defined
>       at deleteTripEntry (:6729:10)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM475 login:1)
>   deleteTripEntry @ VM472:6729
>   onclick @ VM475 login:1

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What is your question?  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: What's the point of this "question"? The error message is very clear, it says, that you haven't defined `contextApplicationPath` variable, which is a part of the expression you're trying to pass to `$.post` function.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, it says that `contextApplicationPath` is not defined. Try declaring the variable or try declaring it before defining `deleteTripEntry` function.

Since your question doesn't have much details, I cannot help further.